# using`varchar` and `nvarchar` columns in the same table and database?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, varchar, nvarchar

Are there any possible implications if I have `varchar` and `nvarchar` columns in the same table or database? 
--Additional Details--
I have a database with 'varchar'  and now I want to convert everything to unicode data types nvarchar. But someone from the team suggested that we shouldn't touch a specific column because anyway it will take only varchar characters e.g. the inherited collation. Now, is there a case we can get any problems in future if we adopt his suggestion? We are not going to compare the varchar column with a nvarchar.

Comment: I have read a lot about unicode and sql server yes. I have a database with 'varchar' and 'char' and now I want to convert everything to unicode data types nvarchar and nchar. But someone from the team suggested that we shouldn't touch a specific column because anyway it will take only varchar characters e.g. the inherited collation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, feel free to have one of the types, both of them or neither.

Just remember that if you want to store unicode, or think that in any time in the future you'll store unicode - choose nvarchar. It takes more space for each character, but it usually doesn't really matter (and when it does, if you enable compression on the table there is also a unicode compression that helps reduce the space).

Comment: Yeah I know that, thanks for pointing out. I probably express my question badly. What I mean is. I have a column of the datatype varchar and one column of the datatype nvarchar in the same database.

Comment: No problems with that.

Comment: can you edit your initial answer so I can accept it?